# Passing data response of first request to second request

Tags: jmeter

I have a GET request from where I wont extract value from SAML Request (example : [https://195.168.124.124/saml/sso?SAMLRequest=jJLdTgIxEIVfZdP77i8s0LCbIMRIgoYAeuGNqd0BSnbbtdNF5ektCyRqIvGyk3PmzDfTIfKqrNmosVu1gLcG0HrTSUZeel0xGIRJh6ZJ1KOdJO7Qfj9MKQfRTboppAMREu8JDEqtMhL77jVFbGCq0HJlXSmMIxrFNA5XYZ%2fFKQuTZ%2bLNjbZa6PJGqkKqTUYao5jmKJEpXgEyK9hydD9jriN7PYmQ3a1Wc7qAQhoQlngjRDDWBY%2b1wqYCswSzlwIeF7OMbK2tkQUBwkFxa9H6TryX6O8atE7ki0NwpEa5UVIRb%2bKYpVO2HBfzjnM8Wn95AkRNvI%2bqVMjazV2fvz7Dknx4VLN2Qeab%2f7qdXzBJ%2fh%2boYTviOeSUWLMH13U6metSik%2fvVpuKu9P8FRr5UVuRBV23UtYorEHItYTCrb0s9fvYALeQEWsaIF6Qn1J%2ffqH8CwAA%2f%2f8DAA%3d%3d"](https://195.168.124.124/saml/sso?SAMLRequest=jJLdTgIxEIVfZdP77i8s0LCbIMRIgoYAeuGNqd0BSnbbtdNF5ektCyRqIvGyk3PmzDfTIfKqrNmosVu1gLcG0HrTSUZeel0xGIRJh6ZJ1KOdJO7Qfj9MKQfRTboppAMREu8JDEqtMhL77jVFbGCq0HJlXSmMIxrFNA5XYZ%2fFKQuTZ%2bLNjbZa6PJGqkKqTUYao5jmKJEpXgEyK9hydD9jriN7PYmQ3a1Wc7qAQhoQlngjRDDWBY%2b1wqYCswSzlwIeF7OMbK2tkQUBwkFxa9H6TryX6O8atE7ki0NwpEa5UVIRb%2bKYpVO2HBfzjnM8Wn95AkRNvI%2bqVMjazV2fvz7Dknx4VLN2Qeab%2f7qdXzBJ%2fh%2boYTviOeSUWLMH13U6metSik%2fvVpuKu9P8FRr5UVuRBV23UtYorEHItYTCrb0s9fvYALeQEWsaIF6Qn1J%2ffqH8CwAA%2f%2f8DAA%3d%3d%22)) and use to the another get calling [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUUt8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `SAMLRequest` parameter from the previous response URL the easiest would be adding a [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) as a child of that previous request and configure it like:

[image]

It will extract the request ID from the URL and store it into `SAMLRequest` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

You may also find [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) article useful as I'm under impression that this `SAMLRequest` should be extracted from the response body, not from the request URL.